# Recursive definition of positive real Number

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, polynomial-math

The following is a recursive definition of positive real numbers from book "Computer Theory" by I. Cohen.

1. 1 is in positive R
2. If x and y are in R, then so x+y, xy, and x/y

but the author said that

> it does define some set, but it is not the set of positive real numbers

What does it mean as all the positive numbers are in the set defined by the above definition?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math rather than programming.  math.stackexchange.com might be a better place for it.

Comment: Okay, Jim I wasn't aware of it, I only come here to ask and answer question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are all rational operations, so that set is not the positive real numbers because it doesn't include any positive irrational numbers (e.g. `sqrt(2)`).

Comment: well, but what about x/y, it can produce irrational too, aren't?.

Comment: If x and y are rational then x/y is also rational.

Comment: if we want to make it R then another condition squrroot(x) is enough?

Comment: No. Allowing `sqrt(x)` will give you an algebraic number field much smaller than R; it doesn't even include e.g. cube roots of rationals (thus the insoluble ancient geometric problem of "doubling the cube"). Even if you include the roots of any polynomial with rational coefficients, that only results in the algebraic numbers, and will not include e.g. pi. The usual way to define R would be to add the axiom that any subset of R which is bounded above has a least upper bound in R. (One constructive definition of a real number is a Dedekind cut).